# Why travis-ci's nosetests keep failing, while nosetests doesn't fail on my pc?

Tags: python-2.7, travis-ci, nosetests

I have built few test function for my little project, and for some reason the nosetests keep failing when Travis-CI builds it. However, when I run the nosetests on my own PC, it passes.

I appreciate any comment, mostly I'm looking for a general reason. If however you can understand what is wrong, I'll be greatful!

Here is the build that failed. The current status is passing because I removed that test function.

https://travis-ci.org/hosseinsadeghi/rateeq/builds/68922729